# Twitter API: Log in Issue

Tags: twitter

I am trying to log in to my twitter account through the developer's section. But instead I get this error message 
"sorry, we couldn't log you in with this twitter account. Double check your credentials and be sure your email address is confirmed".
I was able to log in to my normal twitter account..Can anyone help me with this ?I noticed Twitter  API 1.0 has been deprecated.So I am trying to upgrade to API 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://twitter.com/account/resend_password, type in your email address, and click the submit button. You will receive an email that tells you what to do. Follow the directions in the email.